# C# getting HTTP body using Nancy

Tags: c#, nancy

quick question. I'm using Nancy to convert REST calls to api calls in a project I'm working on. I can't quite get it to work.

I've got Nancy setup and working, for GET requests it's fine. However when I make a POST request using the built in RestClient, like:

```
            restClient.Post("/test", "Param");
```

I can't figure out how to get "Param" out once the call has been made.

I have the NancyModule setup as such:

```
public class TestNancyModule : NancyModule {
    public TestNancyModule() {
        Post["/test"] = p => {
            for(KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> kvp in (DynamicDictionary)p)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint setup inside the NancyModule, which is getting hit when I make a post request to localhost/test, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to extract "Param" out once I'm inside the Nancy module. Ideally I'd be able to just do something like

```
    string POSTParameters = p["Value"]
    //POSTParameters now equals "Param"
```

Any suggestions?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit: I'm leaving the original post up, but I'll clarify here. I was meaning to ask how to access the HTTP body of incoming requests. Unfamiliarity with the protocol led to some errors on my part using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.AsString()` on the body if you pull in `Nancy.Extensions`

```
var thing = Request.Body.AsString();
```

This is the Nancy way.

Comment: Thanks! That's a much nicer way to do it

Comment: method AsString() doesn't exists. Nancy 1.4

Comment: @ArtemG - Note the part " Pull in Nancy.Extensions", i.e. use a using Nancy.Extensions; line in your using clause.

Answer (score 3):

In new versions of NancyFx (1.4+) you can use this solution:

```
using Nancy.IO;
...
var yourString = RequestStream.FromStream(Request.Body).AsString();
```

while

```
var yourString = Request.Body.AsString();
```

is supported no more.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, it's accessible under the "Request" field.

For the code I can get the Body by doing something like

```
            byte[] response = new byte[Request.Body.Length];
            Request.Body.Read(response, 0, (int)Request.Body.Length);
```

and

```
            string POSTParameters = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
```

which is exactly what I was looking for. If the body were going to be more complicated I wouldn't recommend doing such, but I'm only going to be passing in single words for this post.

Answer (score 0):

For query params you can use Nancy's Request object on the module.

```
var queryParam =  this.Request.Query.ParamName;
```

For an actual post body you can use

```
this.Bind();
```

Which will create a dynamic with the properties specified in the body.